# Installing Kaleidescope Requires Git credentials

Tags: git, kaleidoscope

I have a Git repository that I have been using with stored credentials, but after installing Kaleidoscope I have to input my Git credentials each time I use Git. How do I solve this? I have tried using several methods to cache the username and password, but nothing seems to work when I try.

I have tried using:

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

But I still get the request for password.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have read that page, and the solution isn't working for me. I've updated my question.